# ELF interpreter error

Tags: centos6, glibc

When I execute ANY command, this happens.

> /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2: bad ELF interpreter: No such file or directory

I believe I accidentally removed glibc. Is there any way to install it? Non of the commands works. The system is CentOS 6, on a 1GB RAM VPS.

Answer (score 1):

You can reinstall Glibc from an external system only, since the installing binaries use glibc. After booting up a rescue image mount the root of your system somewhere and download the glibc version that you would like to install and execute the following:

```
rpm -Uvh --root=/mnt/broken_system/ --force glibc-X.rpm
```

This install back the Glibc on your system so you can reboot your operating system and it will work.

Comment: RPM command does not work: /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2: bad ELF interpreter: No such file or directory

And, it is a VPS.

Comment: You have to ask the VPS guys to help you if you don't have access to any console. Removed glibc can be fixed only by external process.

Comment: What exactly should I ask them to do?

Comment: to boot up your server using a rescue cd or pendrive and mount your root partition and install glibc the way i mentioned above.

Answer (score 1):

Use below Command to remove

```
sudo yum remove java
```

example now i removing java

Comment: Is this answer related to this question? The original question was about glibc rather than Java.

Answer (score 0):

If you have only removed the symbolic links associated with glibc, you can recover it back by running **ldconfig** utility. It is a **static binary** and hence can be run successfully on broken glibc systems. On some distos, ldconfig would be a script which internally calls something like ldconfig.real, which is again a static binary.